# About the underlying mechanism of openmp parallization

Tags: fortran, openmp

My question related to this website
https://curc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming/OpenMP-Fortran.html

The following Fortran code

```
PROGRAM Parallel_Ordered_Hello
USE OMP_LIB

INTEGER :: thread_id

!$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(thread_id)

    thread_id = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
    DO i=0,OMP_GET_MAX_THREADS()
        PRINT *, "Hello from process: ", thread_id
    END DO

!$OMP END PARALLEL

END
```

leads to output like

```
 Hello from process:            0
 Hello from process:            0
 Hello from process:            0
 Hello from process:            0
 Hello from process:            0
 Hello from process:            1
 Hello from process:            1
 Hello from process:            1
 Hello from process:            2
 Hello from process:            2
 Hello from process:            2
 Hello from process:            2
 Hello from process:            2
 Hello from process:            3
 Hello from process:            3
 Hello from process:            3
 Hello from process:            3
 Hello from process:            3
 Hello from process:            1
 Hello from process:            1
```

The above output looks like one thread after the other (not totally, thread 1 seems to be spitted into two parts). Hence, they look somehow serial. What does openmp do actually?

Comment: The threads are totally independent. Any ordering is possible. If you run it multiple times do you always get the same output?

Answer (score 3):

Most OpenMP implementations (with some clever exceptions) do exactly the same thing -- they outline each parallel region in its own function and then run it in multiple threads.

```
PROGRAM Parallel_Ordered_Hello
USE OMP_LIB

INTEGER :: thread_id, j

j = 0

!$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(thread_id) SHARED(j)

    thread_id = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
    DO i=0,OMP_GET_MAX_THREADS()
        PRINT *, "Hello from process: ", thread_id
    END DO
    
    !$OMP ATOMIC UPDATE
    j = j + thread_id

!$OMP END PARALLEL

END
```

becomes something like

```
PROGRAM Parallel_Ordered_Hello
USE OMP_LIB

TYPE omp_data
    INTEGER, POINTER :: j
END TYPE

INTEGER :: thread_id
INTEGER, TARGET :: j
TYPE(omp_data) :: omp_shared_data

j = 0

omp_shared_data%j => j
CALL _libomp_parallel(omp_func1, omp_shared_data)

END


SUBROUTINE omp_func1(omp_shared_data)
USE OMP_LIB

TYPE(omp_data) :: omp_shared_data
INTEGER :: thread_id, i

    thread_id = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
    DO i=0,OMP_GET_MAX_THREADS()
        PRINT *, "Hello from process: ", thread_id
    END DO

    CALL _libomp_atomic_increment(omp_shared_data%j, thread_id)

END SUBROUTINE
```

I've increased the complexity a bit by adding a shared variable just to show how such variables are handled. `omp_func1` is the outlined content of the parallel region. It is executed in multiple threads by the call to `_libomp_parallel()` (this is not a real function, just a mock-up). The threads run concurrently and there is absolutely no guarantee as to the order in which their output appears.

If you are interested in how different OpenMP constructs are transformed into "regular" code, GCC frontends such as `gfortran` accept the `-fdump-tree-all` option that makes them dump the intermediate code representation at various compilation steps to text files, one for each stage. The code is C-like and somewhat hard to read, but it provides great insights into how GCC handles OpenMP. Of particular interest are the `.omplower` and `.ompexp` files.

Note that in the example you've provided there are two instances of implicit determinations regarding `i`. First, its type is implicitly determined as `INTEGER` from its name (starts with `i`). Second, its OpenMP data-sharing attribute is pre-determined as `PRIVATE` following the rule that sequential loop variables are private in the innermost enclosing parallel region or task-generating construct. This is bad programming practice in general. Use both `IMPLICIT NONE` to inhibit Fortran's automatic name-based typing and `DEFAULT(none)` to inhibit OpenMP's automatic data-sharing attribute rules.

By the way, the message should actually read "Hello from **thread** ...".